# Simple CSS Layout design

Tags: html, css, layout

Hello guys i am learning css layout and a have a problem in a very very simple layout design.I just a column located to the left and the rest content. Thanks!!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> Practicing </title>
    <style type="text/css">
    #leftLayer{
        width: 25%;
        height: 100%;
        float: left;
        background-color: orange;

    }
    #section{
        margin-left: 100px;
        background-color: red;
        height: 100%;

    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="leftLayer"></div>
<div id="section"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: **I just a column located to the left and the rest content** - and what is the problem?

Comment: nothing is being displayed!

Comment: Just add something to your divs. For example: `<div id="leftLayer">left</div>
<div id="section">other</div>`

Comment: now the colors are being displayed but just in a line . how will the height and width percentages will work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The height:100% attribute is correctly showing you 100% of the height of th line of text included in the div.

If you want to define a block with display:block; and define the height:500px; then you will have a block with predetermined height you can float:left; and the next column then joins with it.  The margin-left:100px; is not required.

Try this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> Practicing </title>
    <style type="text/css">

    #leftLayer{
        width: 25%;
        float: left;
        background-color: orange;
    }
    .section {
        display:block;
        height:50em;
    }
    #section{
        background-color: red;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="leftLayer" class="section"> content </div>
<div id="section" class="section"> larger content </div>

</body>
</html>
```